# jQuery Date Picker Input Date Format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm currently working on some coding for a hotel booking widget and am using the jQuery UI Date Picker.

The problem is the external booking system the client is using processes the date format as `yyyy-mm-dd` and the client thinks this is confusing people seeing `2012-06-19` in the input box and would like the date shown as in the European format `dd-mm-yyyy` instead on their site.

So basically the form needs to show `dd-mm-yyyy` when the date is picked and then when the submit button is click on the form somehow the date needs to rearrange to `yyyy-mm-dd` before sending the value.

The booking system company say they have many clients that have achieved this but have said they are not 100% sure how this is done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DatePicker can handle this using the options [`altField`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField) and [`altFormat`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat).

> [`altField`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField) : An input element that is to be updated with the selected date from the datepicker. Use the [`altFormat`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat) option to change the format of the date within this field. Leave as blank for no alternate field.

```js
$('#thedate').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  altField: '#thealtdate',
  altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
Shown Field: <input id="thedate" type="text" /><br />
Hidden Field : <input id="thealtdate" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of ways to approach this but this is likely how I would handle it at first glance.

1. add a hidden field to store the new date value.
2. create an event handler for the on submit function of the submit button.
3. In that function create the new date formatted correctly:

   var d = new Date($("oldDateFormatPicker").val());
   $("hiddenField").val(d);
   return true;

Something like that at least the syntax may be a bit off but it's close. In our server side code just point to the hidden field instead of the date picker.